# How can I let the span margin left next to the div, and vertical-align center?

Tags: html, css

How can I let the span margin left next to the div, and vertical-align center?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The red framework is `div`, and green framework is `span`. the outer `div` element is the div.

```
    <div>
      <span style="width: 100%; margin: auto auto auto 0;">0台</span>
    </div>
```

I tried use `margin`, `display:inline-block;` all failed.

I want the `span` move to there:

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

My `div` is use a Col `span` property for width.

```
<Col :span=8>
  <div>
    <span>...
  </div>
</Col>
```

Comment: Post the styles of your div also

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma There is no styles of div.

Comment: Please replicate your issue on a fiddle/codepen/ or Stackoverflow editor. Cause its difficult to find the issue with the info you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **flex**

Created a demo for understanding purpose.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>0台</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please the styling with `display:table` and `display:table-cell`:

```html
<div style="width: 500px;height:200px;display:table;">
          <span style="width:100%; display:table-cell;
          vertical-align:middle;">0台</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding float: left property to the style.

```html
<div style="width: 500px;">
      <span style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto auto 0; float: left">0台</span>
</div>
```